# How do I display the last month with the year?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have stored the date `Nov. 1, 2020` in the variable `fiscalYearStart` and would like to output `Oct. 2020`. Can you please show me how to do this? I have written a function, but I get the message `ERROR TypeError: fiscalYearStart.getMonth is not a function`

My function:

```
public getLastMonth () {
    this.navService.getBeginningOfFiscalYear().subscribe((yearResp: any) => {
      if (yearResp && yearResp.success) {
        const fiscalYearStart = yearResp.fiscalYearStart;
        fiscalYearStart.setMonth(fiscalYearStart.getMonth() - 1);
        const lastMonth = new Date(fiscalYearStart);
        console.log(lastMonth);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Date` constructor, because `fiscalYearStart` it's a string and doesn't have `getMonth` method.

```
const fiscalYearStart = new Date(yearResp.fiscalYearStart);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public getLastMonth () {
    this.navService.getBeginningOfFiscalYear().subscribe((yearResp: any) => {
      if (yearResp && yearResp.success) {
        const fiscalYearStart = new Date(yearResp.fiscalYearStart);
        fiscalYearStart.setMonth(fiscalYearStart.getMonth() - 1);
        const lastMonth = new Date(fiscalYearStart);
        console.log(lastMonth);
      }
    });
  }
```